# Wordpress in Suexec or suphp

Tags: wordpress, php, apache

I have a Hsphere 3.6S.0SPU installation (that I am begging management to get rid of, but anyways...) that has several customer WordPress installations in it.

I have discovered that the only consistant way to permit WordPress to upload stuff is to set the wp-content/upload tree as RWX for the httpd user. This, I know, is terrible because it means that any process running as the httpd user can now write to this directory.

I have discovered that I can't run WordPress under suexec because suexec only works with shell-out binaries, not plug-ins like PHP. I have also discovered that there is a plug-in called suPHP which should do what I want -- but I can't find it.

The shipped apache config file for hsphere does reference suphp, but only in a commented-out manner, and there are no other files in the hsphere tree that refer to it.

My questions:

A) is suphp the correct way for securely running WordPress in a multi-tenant environment? and
B) if so, where might I find it for my environment?

My apache is 1.3.46 on 32-bit CentOS 5.6.

Comment: Or... you could just tell your customers to upload media to `/wp-content/uploads/` using SFTP then they can view and embed the media using WordPress's media library as normal.

Comment: Yes, but being unable to do things through the wordpress interface breaks things like automated updates.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned with WordPress updates for reasons of security when your CentOS and Apache versions are both end of life... [CentOS-5 updates until March 31, 2017](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-fe8a0be91ee3e7dea812e8694491e1dde5b75e6d) and Apache 1.3 ended eons ago and version [1.3 has many exploits](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-3444/Apache-Http-Server-1.3.html).o better time to upgrade your hosting environment. You should be able to get management on board if you tell them they are end of life.